# minecraft forge closes as soon as i launch it. how do i fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I need help with Minecraft forge 1.7.2

It seems to close (but not crash) forge as soon as it starts. I don't seem to know what to do (this means I have no crash reports for you or any error that pops up :/)
I think it has something to do with my computer, ( I have a dell windows 7 premium 64-bit ). or Java

I have tried everything. re-install forge, delete libraries, magic launcher, etc. Still closes once launched

Just in case here is all my log files.

[fml-junk-earlysetup](http://www.mediafire.com/view/5751k6ss1lq85kd/fml-junk-earlystartup.log)

[fml-client-latest](http://www.mediafire.com/view/rdm4x1xot3mjrfr/fml-client-latest.log)

No space for that kind of text.

I suggest u download files and take a look at them. (no virus here ;p)

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way but you're more likely to get assistance with this if you can paste your log contents into something like Pastebin. Most people will be uneasy downloading random files from an upload site like mediafire. And in some cases, they won't be able to even get to the site (like myself) due to website filtering on a corporate network.

Comment: Have you tried Reinstalling Java?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we [no longer provide support for modded versions of Minecraft, including Forge](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10391/28182)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you have mods installed or not, so I am going to give you a solution for both situations.

What is happening is that you have a Null Pointer Exception. This means there is an error somewhere in the programming where a variable is not found or something similar. There could be a lot of cause for this error.

**If you have no mods installed** and only Minecraft Forge, it could mean that you did not install it correctly. Force an update on Minecraft and re-install Forge by following the exact steps.

**If you have mods installed**, the error could be caused by conflicting mods, which are two mods that are not able to work if another one is installed. Most of the time, conflicting mods does not work because they edit the same bit of data in the game files and the mods that is last loaded overwrite the data of the first mod which cause the first mod to crash since what it need is not there or not correctly programmed. Uninstall all of your mods (forcing an update is a good way, but you'll need to re-install Forge) and re-install them all one by one. Once it crashes, you'll be able to identify which mods is in conflict with another one. One of your options is to stop using one of the two mods. You can also contact the mod authors so they can try to make the mod compatible, but this is a lot of trouble for them.

It does not have anything to do with your computer. Updating Java could help but I do not think this is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had the same problem. Make sure you open eula.txt, and change:

> eula=false

to

> eula=true

Comment: This seems to be the top result on Google for "minecraft forge closes". So I hope this helps people.